# Error [$injector:unpr] when injecting sanitize dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use `progressBar` from [AngularUIBootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I have a **objectFactory.js** file:

```
(function () {
    var objectiveFactory = function ($http, animate) {
        debugger;
        return {
            getObjectives: function () {                
                return $http.get('/api/Objective/');
            }
        };

    };
    debugger;
    try {
        //objectiveFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$animate', '$sanitize'];// error
        objectiveFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$animate'];// no error
        angular.module('app', []).factory('objectiveFactory', objectiveFactory);
    }
    catch (e)
    {}    
}());
```

It is really weird, however if I add new dependency `$sanitize`:

```
objectiveFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$animate', '$sanitize'];// not working
```

Then I've got an error:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=sanitizeProvider%20%3C-%20sanitize%20%3C-%20objectiveController
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost:15533/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:412
>       at http://localhost:15533/Scripts/angular.min.js:43:174
>       at Object.d [as get]

**But `'$http'` and `'$animate',`injections perfectly works.**

I've explored a lot of info and double checked the following advices in my Web API application:

1. I've checked versions `angular'js` file and `angular-sanitize.js` and they are the same `1.5.8`.
2. My bundle files look like this:

   ```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",                     
                "~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js",  
                "~/Scripts/objectiveFactory.js",
                "~/Scripts/objective.js"

                ));
   ```
3. I've tried various ways of injection:

   ```
   objectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'objectiveFactory', '$animate', 'ngSanitize'];
   objectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'objectiveFactory', '$animate', '$sanitize'];
   objectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'objectiveFactory', '$animate', 'sanitize'];
   ```

However, the error is the same:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Does anybody know what I've done wrong? (`'$http'`injection perfectly works)

Comment: did u inject ngSanitize into your main module?

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz ooops, what's main module? I just have two JavaScript files: `objectoveFactory` and  `objectiveController`.

Comment: angular.module('app', []) here is your main module and you did not inject anything here. It is normal $https is working because it comes with core but you have to inject ngSanitize to make $sanitize work...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz thanks! It works! Post your answer and I'll mark it!

Comment: Can't he inject it into the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject **ngSanitize** into your main module to work with **$sanitize**...

You need to do same thing for $animate as well, inject **ngAnimate**

Comment: Can't he inject it into the controller? If he had multiple controllers, wouldn't that be more modular?

Comment: @Mawg ngSanitize is an angularjs module so you cannot inject it controller but you can inject it to your module. If you want to use it only in sub modules then inject it only into submodules.

Comment: I was not aware of that! And I only asked because I found this while searching to a problem that I am having while trying to inject directly into the controller. So, plus one to you & now I am off to look for a tutorial :-)